# What would be the time complexity of a loop that runs n-2 times?

Tags: time-complexity

I have a loop that runs `n-2` times, what would be the time complexity in this case.

```
for(int m=1; m<arr.length-1; m++) {

}
```

I am not convinced for it to be O(n) because it will never run n times, not even in worst case scenarios.

Comment: More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation

Answer (score 1):

`O(n)` just means "on the order of n".  Specifically, the definition is that some function `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` if there exist some `k` and `c` such that for all `n > k`, `f(n) < c * g(n)`.  In this case, set `f(n) = n - 2` and `g(n) = n`, you can see that for `k = 10` and `c = 2`, `n < 2 * (n - 2)` for all `n > 10`, so `n - 2` is indeed `O(n)`.